# Project runs normal in Eclipse but doesn't when exported to a runnable jar

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having problems when i try to export my stand-alone application.

It runs ok when I execute it using eclise, but when i try to export to a runnable jar it gives me some errors.

My persistence.xml looks like

```
<persistence-unit transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" name="alctel_server_monitor">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>br.com.monitor.database.vo.Servidor</class>
    <class>br.com.monitor.database.vo.Banco</class>
    <class>br.com.monitor.database.vo.Servico</class>
    <class>br.com.monitor.database.vo.alerta.Alerta</class>
    <class>br.com.monitor.database.vo.alerta.AlertaAtivo</class>
    <class>br.com.monitor.database.vo.email.Email</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.99.222;databaseName=MONITOR;" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor"
            value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding"
            value="UTF-8" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And it's located at src/META-INF/persistence.xml

The stack trace i got when i run it from terminal is:

> > at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
> >     Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
> >     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:99)
> >     at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:93)
> >     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:86)
> >     at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:101)
> >     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:67)
> >     at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
> >     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)

I have no idea what is happening, someone could help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, and i solved by following way:

Right click on the project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export, and select the libraries

Right click on the project > Export... > Runnable JAR file > Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR