# Maven Unable to locate persistence unit

Tags: java, maven, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

Hi I am building a java application with `maven` and `jpa`. I have a database project that is a dependency for my main application. The database project is fully functional in development mode but when i generate a jar i get the error `Unable to locate persistence unit`. I put the `persistence.xml` file in a folder `META-INF` that is located in the same folder as my jar file. I have the following `persistence.xml file`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

        <persistence-unit name="user-db">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <class>com.main.application.User</class>
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pwd" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/users_db" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Stacktrace:

> ```
> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
> >         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
> > Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate
> > persistence units
> >         at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:84)
> >         at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
> >         at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
> >         at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
> >         at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
> >         at com.user.Dao.<init>(Dao.java:22)
> >         at com.user.Dao.get(Dao.java:26)
> >         at com.user.UserHandler.<init>(UserHandler.java:61)
> >         at com.user.Main.main(Main.java:10)
> >         ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
> > -1
> >         at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
> >         at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ArchiveHelper.getJarURLFromURLEntry(ArchiveHelper.java:45)
> >         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:105)
> >         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:84)
> >         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:66)
> >         at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:80)
> >         ... 13 more
> ```

Comment: Post full error trace !

Comment: @localhost999 updated my question

Comment: Could you provide more details about your application package, and where you deploy it? Also check that it complies with rules provided in my answer.

Comment: Hi @Rémi I am compiling a jar file that has my database project as dependency there in the resource folder the META-INF folder is located. I also tried moving the META-INF to both my main project resource folder and in the same folder as my jar file.

Comment: Also it seems that putting the persistence.xml in the META-INF folder located where the jar file is located is working. When I make it a invalid xml file I see that in my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I was exporting my project the wrong way. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073513/project-runs-normal-in-eclipse-but-doesnt-when-exported-to-a-runnable-jar) thread  and and this what was suggested there and everyting seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

As you use JPA-2.0, below is an extract from Java EE 6 JPA [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbrj/index.html) that might be useful:

> Persistent units can be packaged as part of a WAR or EJB JAR file or
>   can be packaged as a JAR file that can then be included in an WAR or
>   EAR file.
>
> - If you package the persistent unit as a set of classes in an EJB JAR
>     file, persistence.xml should be put in the EJB
>     JAR’s META-INF directory.
> - If you package the persistence unit as a set of classes in a WAR
>     file, persistence.xml should be located in the WAR
>     file’s WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory.
> - If you package the persistence unit in a JAR file that will be
>     included in a WAR or EAR file, the JAR file should be located in
>     either
>
>   - The WEB-INF/lib directory of a WAR
>   - The EAR file’s library directory